# Magento 2: Getting error "Unable to find tier for customer "Customer name". Please check tier configuration." while shipping an order in the backend

Tags: magento2, tierprice, shipment

[image]

I am getting the error while shipment order in the backend. I am using Magento 2.3.1 version. I am not using the tier price in my products. Still, I am getting this error.

Comment: it seems like the customer associated with the Order is not available in your website. Please check the customer section for the same.

Comment: No, i hide it for security.

Comment: Can you please share the full order screenshot with order items.

Comment: Can I share it in the email?

Comment: The issue with the tier price configuration for the product. You can check the price configuration for the ordered products for the customer group which the customer belongs.

Comment: I have used products with no tier price setup.
The issue is that if a products has 10 quantity then we can easily shipped the 9 quantity and it shows the message "the shipment has created".
But then we tried for the last quantity then it shows the above error " “Unable to find tier for customer ”Customer name“. Please check tier configuration.”
Do you think any module is conflicting?
I have never see this error before.

Comment: Yes, any third-party module may be the reason for the same.

Comment: Alright, Thanks for your help